# Tracking user activities on facebook

Tags: facebook

I've created a Facebook page and implemented an application for it too. Now, my aim is that, a user must like and share page with at least one friend to be able to participate/to get access to the app and consequently use it (play the game). Or simply force a user to like and share the page. Can you please tell me if this is even possible and how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user visits your Facebook page, you receive [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) , which contains some information about the user, including whether or not the user liked your page. For share, you will probably need to implement [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/). In documentation it is said that user takes action (send or cancel) he will be redirected to url you set up, and if the action was "cancel", there will be an error.

So you will probably need to create db where you store user id and whether or not he shared your page before (since you can check if he liked the page at any time).